# How to Insert Data into Custom Database or u can say that how to use two databases in one Wordpress Site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

UPDATED 
    upload image to desired directory or say that how to go back to public_html...
    first i want to go back three steps at public_html directory than i will go to ibank/login/nfs/uploads and upload image here

```
here is my code details

// IMAGE UPLOAD
$tmp_name = $_FILES["profile-picture"]["name"];

$path_array = wp_upload_dir(); // normal format start
$file_name   =   pathinfo($tmp_name ,PATHINFO_FILENAME).time().".".pathinfo($_FILES["profile-picture"]["name"] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//$test = $tmp_name . "///" .$file_name;
//die($test); 
$imgtype     =   strtolower(pathinfo($tmp_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));                
$targetpath        =  get_site_url().'/ibank/login/nfs/uploads/'.$file_name;  
//UPLOADS_THEME_PATH."/documents/".$file_name;

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $targetpath );

I wanto go back to public_html and than go to my desired path
here is my path....
/ibank/login/nfs/uploads
ibank is in public_html directory not into wp folder
```

Comment: Please see this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-wordpress

Comment: $url1 = get_site_url();
echo $url1;

$url = site_url();
echo $url;

Comment: paste in you code and  provide me, what you can get for both output.

Comment: @PPL nothing display anything
$url1 = get_site_url(); 
$url = site_url(); echo $url1."///".$url;  die($url1."///".$url);

Comment: What you get in echo $url1; and echo $url; so i can get path idea?

Comment: @PPL 
i got this 
$url1  "http://mysiteUrl.com"
$url     "http://mysiteUrl.com"
with http://

Comment: <?php
  $path = getcwd();
  echo $path;
?>

Comment: @PPL it gives /home/decent/public_html

Comment: so, your problem is solved now.

Comment: @PPL but image is not stored into the path using this method

Comment: @PPL why image is not upload into path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define database Like this:

$mydb = new wpdb('decentba_admin','Samsaghir@786','decentba_new','localhost');

```
$s1="INSERT INTO `register_request` (`name`, `dob`, `email`, `mobile`, `address`, `gender`, `id_type`, `password`, `acc_type`, `acc_branch`, `trans_pin`, `open_bal`, `profile_pictures`) VALUES ('$fullName', '$dob', '$email', '$mobnum', '$fullAddress', '$gender', '$idtype', '$pass', '$atype', '$bnkb', '$transpin', '$aob', '$fileNameDb')";
$insert = $mydb->query($s1);
if($insert){
    echo 'success';}
else{
    echo 'error in database';
 }
```